# AIDL working in debug APK but not in signedAPKs

Tags: android, aidl

I have 2 APKs in which I am sharing data using **AIDL**.

When I am installing them by debug apks or build apks, feature of **AIDL**  working fine.

But when I am creating **signed APK** for both with different keys, **AIDL** feature is not working.

Any one faced same issue? Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, when we need to share data in 2 apps, either by SharePreference or **AIDL**, both apps should be signed by same keys.

Or we will need to use **ContentProvider** instead.